# SharePoint Online Communication Site-Not able to remove the white-space on the left

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, page-layout, communication-site

I am using a One-third right column layout and all the webparts appear to be centrally aligned when viewed on an average size monitor. This leaves a noticeable white-space on the left. Is there any way that can be removed?

[image]

I tried using CSS and adjusting the layout of the columns but in vain

```
    .SPCanvas{
 margin-left:0px;
    margin-top:0px;
padding:0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use developer tool to debug, you would see the SPcanvas is full content div so margin won't work as you expected.
[image]

You could try to update the left div padding.

[image]